# apache2 is inactive (No such file or directory)

Tags: server, apt, apache2

I installed apache2 many weeks ago, and it worked for lots of hours until I remove it. I did:

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2*
```

Today I want to install apache2 again. I did

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

and it response

```
正在讀取套件清單... 完成
正在重建相依關係
正在讀取狀態資料... 完成
下列的額外套件將被安裝：
  apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils
建議套件：
  www-browser apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine | apache2-suexec-custom
下列【新】套件將會被安裝：
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils
升級 0 個，新安裝 4 個，移除 0 個，有 76 個未被升級。
需要下載 0 B/1,255 kB 的套件檔。
此操作完成之後，會多佔用 5,403 kB 的磁碟空間。
是否繼續進行 [Y/n]？ [Y/n] Y
選取了原先未選的套件 apache2-bin。
（讀取資料庫 ... 目前共安裝了 152131 個檔案和目錄。）
Preparing to unpack .../apache2-bin_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apache2-bin (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5) ...
選取了原先未選的套件 apache2-utils。
Preparing to unpack .../apache2-utils_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apache2-utils (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5) ...
選取了原先未選的套件 apache2-data。
Preparing to unpack .../apache2-data_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5_all.deb ...
Unpacking apache2-data (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5) ...
選取了原先未選的套件 apache2。
Preparing to unpack .../apache2_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apache2 (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu19) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.35-0ubuntu2) ...
Rules updated for profile 'Apache Full'

設定 apache2-bin (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5) ...
設定 apache2-utils (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5) ...
設定 apache2-data (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5) ...
設定 apache2 (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5) ...
```

But after installing apache2, there is no file in the folder `/etc/apache2`, and I can't find apache2 in the folder `/etc/init.d`.

When I do

```
sudo systemctl status apache2
```

I got

```
Warning: apache2.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
● apache2.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

And I did

> systemctl daemon-reload

I got (I entered the password)

```
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.reload-daemon ===
Authentication is required to reload the systemd state.
Authenticating as: ****,,,(****)
Password:
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
```

But it is still inactive.
What can I do? It annoys me for many days.

Comment: Please run it like so `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

Comment: @Melebius Yes, I did it, but it was still inactive. Thank for your notice. I will edit my question.

Comment: Did you try `sudo systemctl status apache2` again?

Comment: @derHugo Yes, but I got the same response.

Comment: Can you check that `apt-get install` command finished successfully? Please add the output of `apt list --installed 'apache*'` or run `sudo apt-get install apache2` again and post its full output.

Comment: Any suspicious output during the installation with `apt-get`?

Comment: @Melebius
$ apt list --installed 'apache*'
Listing... 完成
apache2/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5 amd64 [installed]
apache2-bin/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
apache2-data/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5 all [installed,automatic]
apache2-utils/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5 amd64 [installed,automatic]

Comment: @derHugo I think everything is fine. I edit my question with post the output when apt-get install.